# Looking for the name of a scifi comic/graphic novel

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

This one is difficult to explain as I never read it, but always intended to.

It is either a graphic novel, or a comic. There were at least 2 books/comics.

From what I can remember, there was an alien(from best memory) and I think trying to find his way home or was trying to find someone, may have also been a genetically created being, or an android.
The art style was all done in a single colour, but shades of that particular colour. One of them was shades of Orange the other shades of Blue.

My best recollection of a time frame was about 2 years ago I saw it, and I'm not certain if it was currently out, or soon to be out.

I've got a single image in my head, where it is an alien/android sitting against a cliff, or possibly in a  dried up river.
No idea on the language, most likely English, but considering I have the inkling it wasn't out yet, it's possible a translation was being waited upon.(I'm thinking possible eastern European if that was the case)

Any help would be incredibly appreciated

Comment: Please update your question with the info here - welcome!

http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question